# Laravel maatwebsite Export Excel and PDF

Tags: laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I am using maatwebsite Excel Laravel Package.
Using same Export Class can I use View to PDF import and Model to Excel;

To PDF Export I want to use View File

```php
public function view(): View
    {
        return view('exports.invoices', [
            'invoices' => Invoice::all()
        ]);
    }
return Excel::download(new InvoicesExport, 'invoices.pdf', \Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::MPDF);
```

Incase of Excel

```
return Excel::download(new InvoicesExport, 'invoices.xls', \Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::XLS);
```

No View File

Comment: Do you mean your excel sheet downloads rather than viewing in browser?  If so, I'm afraid that is just how the browsers work, they do not have a buildt in Excel viewer.

Comment: No,PDF render should use View and Excel Render should not use View file